# $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$ and $\int g(x)<\infty\Rightarrow\ \int f(x)<\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, intuition, improper-integrals

> Let f,g continious functions on $[0,\infty)$ s.t $\forall x\in[0,\infty), |f(x)|\le|g(x)|$. Prove or give counterexample thtat if $\int_ 0^\infty g(x)dx<\infty$ then $\int_0^\infty f(x)<\infty$.

I think that's incorrect but I can't find any good example. If it'd be $|f(x)|\ge |g(x)|$, I could have given example of $g(x)=\frac {\sin{x}}{x}$ and $f(x)=\frac 1 x$. Which counterexample can I give? what is the intuition for such questions?

Comment: Is this Riemann integration or Lebesgue? That should make a difference. If this means nothing to you, then it must be Riemann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example, with some modification, works. We just get rid of the $\frac{1}{x}$.

Let $g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, and let $f(x)=|g(x)|$. It seems clear that you are aware that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$$
converges.

The fact that 
$$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx$$
diverges is likely familiar to you. If proof is needed, note that between $n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $|\sin x|\ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Note that $|f| < |g|$. This is not the case in your example. A slight modification is all that is required.

Comment: The inequality in the title was strict. The inequality in the body was not. I chose the body, because it looked more like a direct quotation. And it was shorter to deal with!

Comment: Oh I didn't even see that. But to address the strict inequality (just in case), it suffices to just add a positive, decaying exponential to your $g$.

Comment: Choosing $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{2x}$ will also make the inequality strict.

Comment: @SteveKass:  It won't, since $\sin x$ is $0$ infinitely often.

Comment: Ah, right - your answer is what's needed.